# Improving node.xpath('//')

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I find myself doing the following to find one node that can occur at potentially multiple xpaths, but the node itself will only appear once:

```
node.xpath('//Parent')
```

This will search **all** paths in order to find the `Parent` element. However, it only appears once (though it could appear at potentially 10 or so possible paths and is quite tedious to write out). Is there a method that I can use that will more efficiently find -- and exit -- when the first element is returned instead of building a list of all nodes at that path?

Comment: short-circuiting/keeping only part of the result is mentioned briefly [here](https://lxml.de/3.7/performance.html#xpath). [lxml, like ElementTree, supports ElementPath](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elementpath), and while it is less powerful than XPath, it does include the method `find()` which according to the docs _efficiently returns only the first match_.

Comment: @AMC I am not sure what "efficiently" means there, but it looks like the entire document needs to be parsed before `find()` can be called. So, it might solve the problem of unnecessarily retrieving several results for an XPath expression, but still unnecessarily build a representation of the entire document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't have to use XPath and can identify the element in question by its name. Then you could use [event-driven parsing](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#event-driven-parsing) - also called "SAX" parsing - instead of the conventional "DOM" parsing that lxml is doing by default.

Code would be similar to (pseudo code)

```
some_file_like = BytesIO(b"<root><a>data</a></root>")
for event, element in etree.iterparse(some_file_like):
    if element.tag == "Parent":
        act_on(element)
        break
```

---

Alternatively, a very similar method would be to use a SAX parser implementation in Python, such as https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.reader.html. This would give you more fine-grained control over the parsing, as you would write custom callbacks that are executed when a certain type of event is encountered.

An example, adapted from [here](https://gist.github.com/veryhappythings/98604):

```
from xml.sax import saxutils, handler, make_parser

class ContentGenerator(handler.ContentHandler):

    def __init__(self, out = sys.stdout):
        handler.ContentHandler.__init__(self)

    def startDocument(self):
        pass

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == "Parent":
            # act on this element
```